# Docker is always loading the wrong PHP version that I have setup in Dockerfile

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am currently learning Docker for a project and got a configuration to start on my PHP website that I intend to change. The problem is that even when I set up different versions in Dockerfile I get the same PHP version.

This is the output when I do the **docker-compose up** command.
[image: Text]
It keeps using the PHP version 7.0.33. That's the version that it shows in the browser as well.

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
# tell docker what version of the docker-compose.yml were using
version: '3'
# define the network
networks:
  web-network:

# start the services section
services:
  # define the name of our service
  # corresponds to the "--name" parameter
  docker-php-cli:
    # define the directory where the build should happened,
    # i.e. where the Dockerfile of the service is located
    # all paths are relative to the location of docker-compose.yml
    build: 
      context: ./php-apache
    # reserve a tty - otherwise the container shuts down immediately
    # corresponds to the "-i" flag
    tty: true
    # mount the app directory of the host to /var/www in the container
    # corresponds to the "-v" option
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www
    # connect to the network
    # corresponds to the "--network" option
    networks:
      - web-network

  docker-nginx:
    build: 
      context: ./nginx
    # defines the port mapping
    # corresponds to the "-p" flag
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www
      - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    networks:
      - web-network

  docker-php-fpm:
    build: 
      context: ./php-fpm
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www
    networks:
      - web-network
```

These are the Docker files:
php-apache folder

```
FROM php:5.6-apache
RUN pecl install xdebug-2.6.0 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
```

php-fpm folder

```
FROM php:5.6-fpm
RUN pecl install xdebug-2.6.0 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
```

I would like to change it for PHP 5.6 but I couldn't, then I tested with many other versions and it didn't work.

I did try removing the RUN part from each Dockerfile.

Can someone help me with that?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you do a `docker-compose build` before `up`?

Comment: You can force a build in the up command with: `docker-compose up --build`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are using `docker-compose up` what that command does is, it's start containers from previously build images(to see images on you local use `docker image ls`)

after changing Dockerfile what you need to do is run `docker-compose down`
and up again with --build flag. `docker-compose up --build`

> Relevant document https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/

Comment: Thank you, I noticed that with the previous comment. =)
Now it is working, will just setup the mysql.